# How do you pre-process within a tensorflow estimator?

Tags: tensorflow

I have two input features. I want to divide one by the other and create a third input feature.

Most of the documentation I've found related to pre-processing is related to using the input_fn or feature_engineering_fn. 
I do my model creation in python and the model is served in C++ and will probably be using tensorflow_serving in the future so I can't just re-use my python input_fn/feature_engineering_fn code.

Is there another way to do this such that this becomes an op in the model itself?

Comment: How about just adding the division operation into your model? Are you trying to use some specific high-level API? If so, please give more details. Without them the questions trivial.

Comment: Any tensorflow high level estimator, such as DNNLinearCombinedRegressor.evaluate()